# What is the syntax to define a Postgres procedure within an another stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating my Oracle DB to Postgres. But there is an Oracle procedure like this:

```sql
create or replace
PROCEDURE TOP_PROCEDURE
(...)
IS
   variable NUMBER;
   PROCEDURE nested_procedure (...)
   IS
   BEGIN
     NULL;
   END;
   PROCEDURE another_nested_procedure (...)
   IS
   BEGIN
     NULL;
   END;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
```

PG doesn't support this syntax. I try to convert these nested procedure to global procedure.

But there are too many nested procedures waiting me to convert.

I wonder if PG supports nested procedure? And what's the syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't support this.

I recommend creating a special schema that contains all auxiliary functions, then they won't clutter the schema that contains the main function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used to worried that too many global functions may cause some troubles. Put them into a schema can really work. 